# Webservice returns a SoapPrimitive containing escaped XML

Tags: android, xml, soap, ksoap2

I have run across a WS that returns a SoapPrimitive containing raw XML as a string. As you can see in this example response, the contents of the ResultXML element is a string which is itself some kind of escaped XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><GetJourneyPathResponse xmlns="http://www.etis.fskab.se/v1.0/ETISws"><GetJourneyPathResult><Code>0</Code><Message /><ResultXML>&lt;Part&gt;&lt;From&gt;&lt;Id&gt;254197...
```

Normally I would do something like

```
SoapObject soapObject = (SoapObject) response.getProperty("EndPoints");
```

but in this case it is not working (classcastexception). This is because (I think) KSOAP sees the result as a string primitive rather then a complex object. So instead I do

```
SoapPrimitive Partsp = (SoapPrimitive) response.getProperty("ResultXML");
```

This works, and I now have access to the XML in the string. But what next?

I would prefer to convert the XML string into a SoapObject so that I can carry on my merry way. Is that possible?

This SOAP response seems rather screwed up to me, but there is not a lot I can do about it.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting your response? Have you tried debugging to see what the response looks like. This is definitely weird and not how it should be.

Comment: this ws is 1 of a familly of about 5. The other 3 I am using return SoapObjects and all is well. I dont do anything different when calling this WS. It is the contents of the response that is different.

Comment: On 2nd thought, trying to turn the XML string into a SoapObject is probably a bad idea. The XML contains a lot of coordinates making up a route. I probably just want to parse the string. I dont have any experience of this in Java, but from what I have read the XMLPullParser might be easiest and fastest

Comment: it automatically is a SoapObject tree when you call getResponse and you just need to parse it. If you use XMLPullParser you might want to NOT use ksoap for it otherwise you doing it twice..